# Is there a way to make this code smaller? [SWIFT]

Tags: swift

Is there a way to make this smaller like a way to make it only a few lines just wanted to know if i could make it smaller

```
button[0].setTitle(btnsNxt[0], for: .normal)
button[1].setTitle(btnsNxt[1], for: .normal)
button[2].setTitle(btnsNxt[2], for: .normal)
button[3].setTitle(btnsNxt[3], for: .normal)
button[4].setTitle(btnsNxt[4], for: .normal)
button[5].setTitle(btnsNxt[5], for: .normal)
button[6].setTitle(btnsNxt[6], for: .normal)
button[7].setTitle(btnsNxt[7], for: .normal)
button[8].setTitle(btnsNxt[8], for: .normal)
button[9].setTitle(btnsNxt[9], for: .normal)
button[10].setTitle(btnsNxt[10], for: .normal)
button[11].setTitle(btnsNxt[11], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Why are you asking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it through a loop:

```
for n in 0...11 { button[n].setTitle(btnsNxt[n], for: .normal) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it where `enumerated()` will give you a collection of tuples containing button and index that we use `forEach` to loop through

```
button.enumerated().forEach {$1.setTitle(btnsNxt[$0], for: .normal)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
zip(button,btnsNxt).forEach { $0.setTitle($1, for: .normal) }
```